# Unpack a R data frame column of lists

Tags: r, data.table

In R I have a data.frame (or data.table). Within this data.frame i have a column were every cell consists out of a list of lists (a data.frame).

I can convert this column into a single data.frame by `rbindlist(data$Subdocuments)` but here are the other columns of the origional data.frame missing.

How to efficient unpack this column of lists, but keep the other columns attached to the new data.frame?

```
     library(data.table)

    data <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3"), Country = c("Netherlands", 
"Germany", "Belgium"), Subdocuments = list(structure(list(Value = c("5", 
"5", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "5", "3", "2", "4", "5", 
"5", "2"), Label = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", 
"Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12", 
"Test13", "Test14", "Test15", "Test16"), Year = c(2001, 2002, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016)), .Names = c("Value", "Label", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
16L)), structure(list(Value = c("5", "4", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "5", "4", "4", "4", "5", "1", "1", "3"), Label = c("Test1", 
"Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", 
"Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12", "Test13", "Test14", "Test15", 
"Test16"), Year = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016)), .Names = c("Value", 
"Label", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 16L
)), structure(list(Value = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "4", "5", 
"1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "5"), Label = c("Test1", 
"Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", 
"Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12", "Test13", "Test14", "Test15", 
"Test16"), Year = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016)), .Names = c("Value", 
"Label", "Year"), class = "data.table", row.names = c(NA, 16L
)))), .Names = c("ID", "Country", "Subdocuments"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your data showed lots of `NA` rows in the `list` column.

Comment: @akrun Sorry there was something wrong in the dput of the data.frame. I solved it.

Comment: perhaps `setDT(data)[, .SD[[1L]][[1L]], by=.(ID, Country)]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do

```
setDT(data)

dfcol   = "Subdocuments"
othcols = setdiff(names(data), dfcol)

subs = rbindlist(data[[dfcol]], id=TRUE)
subs[, (othcols) := data[.id, othcols, with=FALSE]]
```

If you don't want to `setDT(data)`, you can change the last line like `data[.id, othcols]`.

Comment: When running: `subs = rbindlist(data[[dfcol]], id=TRUE)` I get the following error: `Error in rbindlist(data[[dfcol]], id = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (id = TRUE)`

Comment: @Berecht Please update your data.table to `1.9.6` as the `id` functionality is recent

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(setNames(data[[3]], do.call(paste, data[1:2])), idcol=TRUE)[
        , c("ID", "Country") := tstrsplit(.id, " ")][, .id := NULL][]
# Value  Label Year ID     Country
# 1:     5  Test1 2001  1 Netherlands
# 2:     5  Test2 2002  1 Netherlands
# 3:     1  Test3 2003  1 Netherlands
# 4:     3  Test4 2004  1 Netherlands
# 5:     2  Test5 2005  1 Netherlands
# 6:     1  Test6 2006  1 Netherlands
# 7:     1  Test7 2007  1 Netherlands
# 8:     1  Test8 2008  1 Netherlands
# 9:     2  Test9 2009  1 Netherlands
#10:     5 Test10 2010  1 Netherlands
#11:     3 Test11 2011  1 Netherlands
#12:     2 Test12 2012  1 Netherlands
#13:     4 Test13 2013  1 Netherlands
#14:     5 Test14 2014  1 Netherlands
#15:     5 Test15 2015  1 Netherlands
#16:     2 Test16 2016  1 Netherlands
#17:     5  Test1 2001  2     Germany
#18:     4  Test2 2002  2     Germany
#19:     3  Test3 2003  2     Germany
#20:     2  Test4 2004  2     Germany
#21:     2  Test5 2005  2     Germany
#22:     2  Test6 2006  2     Germany
#23:     1  Test7 2007  2     Germany
#24:     1  Test8 2008  2     Germany
#25:     5  Test9 2009  2     Germany
#26:     4 Test10 2010  2     Germany
#27:     4 Test11 2011  2     Germany
#28:     4 Test12 2012  2     Germany
#29:     5 Test13 2013  2     Germany
#30:     1 Test14 2014  2     Germany
#31:     1 Test15 2015  2     Germany
#32:     3 Test16 2016  2     Germany
#33:     1  Test1 2001  3     Belgium
#34:     2  Test2 2002  3     Belgium
#35:     3  Test3 2003  3     Belgium
#36:     1  Test4 2004  3     Belgium
#37:     1  Test5 2005  3     Belgium
#38:     4  Test6 2006  3     Belgium
#39:     5  Test7 2007  3     Belgium
#40:     1  Test8 2008  3     Belgium
#41:     2  Test9 2009  3     Belgium
#42:     3 Test10 2010  3     Belgium
#43:     2 Test11 2011  3     Belgium
#44:     2 Test12 2012  3     Belgium
#45:     1 Test13 2013  3     Belgium
#46:     1 Test14 2014  3     Belgium
#47:     1 Test15 2015  3     Belgium
#48:     5 Test16 2016  3     Belgium
```

NOTE: The 'data' is from the OP's own post.

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(data[[3]], .id="ID") %>% 
            left_join(data[-3], ., by = "ID")
```

Comment: I got the following error: `Error in rbindlist(setNames(data[[3]], do.call(paste, data[1:2])), idcol = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (idcol = TRUE)`. Maybe the problem is the version of the package data.table i am using (1.9.4). I will check this now.

Comment: @Berecht It is the version problem.  I use 1.9.6

Comment: @Berecht this answer pastes columns and then splits them, thus converting everything to strings and losing information. In addition to that, it copies the same data multiple times for no good reason. Definitely not the way to go.